# Problem of probability distribution

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, expected-value

**A box contains $N$ tickets numbered $1, 2, 3,...., N$. If $m$ tickets are drawn one by one from the box without replacement, then find the mean of the sum of the numbers obtained on the tickets drawn.**

I have approached the sum as below.

Let $X_i$ denote the number on the $i$th ticket drawn, where $i= 1, 2,..., m$.

The sum of the numbers obtained on the tickets drawn is $S= \sum_{i=1}^{m}X_i$

Hence, the required mean
$= E(S)
  =E(\sum_{i=1}^{m}X_i)
  =\sum_{i=1}^{m}E(X_i).$

Each $X_i$ can take the values $1, 2,...,  N$ with probability $\frac{1}{N}$.
Then $E(X_i)= \frac{N+1}{2}$

So, $E(S)= \frac{m(N+1)}{2}$

But my doubt is in the above line 'Each $X_i$ can take the values $1, 2,..., N$ with probability $\frac{1}{N}$.'
Because when the drawing is done without replacement, after each draw, the number of tickets remaining decreases by 1. So the number of values left for $X_2$ is $N-1$, not $N$.
So how can the probability be $\frac{1}{N}$?

Will anyone please explain where is the mistake?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Ingix Right you are.

Comment: By symmetry, each number must have the same chance of being drawn on draw $i$ so the probability, *before the first number is drawn* that $X_i=k$ for any $i,k$ must be $\frac1N.$  You are correct that the probabilities change as the process continues, but your calculation is also correct, because you are computing the expectation before the first number is drawn.  After the first number is drawn, the (conditional) expectation is different.

Comment: Use the [$\texttt{Linearity of expectation}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Linearity): $E(X_i)=E(X_j), \forall \ 1\leq i,j\leq N$. It is easy to calculate that $E(X_1)=\frac{N+1}{2}$. Here the probability is constant for every number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So how can the probability be $\frac1N$?

The probability is indeed not  $\frac1N$ if you have drawn at least one ticket. You have to look at the probability to draw a combination. It is a good idea is to look on a small example.

Let´s say a box contains $3$ tickets numbered $1,2,3$. The probabilities to draw number $i$ at the first draw are $P(X_1=1)=P(X_1=2)=P(X_1=3)=\frac13$.

Thus $\mathbb E(X_1)=\sum\limits_{i=1}^3 p(x_i)\cdot x_i=\frac13\cdot 1+\frac13\cdot 2+\frac13\cdot 3=2$

Now what is $\mathbb E(X_2)$?

The probability to draw the combinations $(i,j)$ are

$P(X_2=(1,2))=\frac13\cdot \frac12\cdot 2=\frac13$, $P(X_2=(1,3))=\frac13\cdot \frac12\cdot 2=\frac13$, $P(X_2=(2,3))=\frac13\cdot \frac12\cdot 2=\frac13$

The corresponding means are $1.5,2,2.5$. It follows that the expected value is

$\mathbb E(X_2)=\frac13\cdot (1.5+2+2.5)=2$

It is much more difficult to make a proof for an arbitrary $N$. But  you can use the [Linearity of expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Linearity).

For a uniform, discrete random variable we have $\mathbb E(X_1)=\frac{N+1}2$. Thus $\mathbb E(X_i)=\frac{N+1}2 \ \  \forall \ 1\leq i\leq N$

Answer (score 0):

Your calculation is actually correct, though it is not trivial to see it.

On one hand your argument is right, after the first number is drawn, the second number ($X_2$) only has one of $N-1$ possible values. Even worse, if $X_1=1$, then the expected value of $X_2$ will be $\frac{2+3+\ldots+N}{N-1}=\frac{N^2+N-2}{2(N-1)} > \frac{N+1}2.$

OTOH, the first number could also be $X_1=N$, making the expected value for $X_2$ smaller than $\frac{N+1}2$. In the end, all of this will balance out. It should be pretty intuitive to see that if you don't consider what happens before, the value of $X_i$ can be $1,2,\ldots,N$, each with the same probability $1 \over N$. Overall, there is no higher probability to draw a $4$ than a $7$ on the third draw, for example.

The step that most people have problems with is when you wrote

$$E(\sum_{i=1}^mX_i) = \sum_{i=1}^mE(X_i)$$

This is correct, but most people's intuition is against this, because they say "the $X_i$ are dependend". It turns out, using the integral definition, that the equation is true even if the $X_i$ are dependend (which they of course are in our case).